# Are DateTime.Now and std::chrono::system_clock::now() the same?

Tags: c#, c++, clock, c++-chrono

I am observing some weird problem.

I am subscribing to a WebSocket stream from both C++ and C#, and I am receiving the same event (they have the same sequence ID) with different times. I am stamping `arrivalTime` as soon as I receive a package.

I have this in C++:

```cpp
auto arrivalTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

And have this in C#:

```cs
var arrivalTime = DateTime.Now;
```

And somehow, the C# one is 90% of the time earlier, from few microseconds up to 100ms, although sometimes the C++ one is earlier.

I know there can be some stuff going on my WebSocket libraries on C++ and C# and so on, but I'm just curious - should these 2 calls be the same if called at the same time?

Comment: I think you mean `std::chrono`, not `std::chtono` - unless there's been some major changes to the STL made overnight?

Comment: haha nice one, editted, thanks for spotting

Comment: There are lots of reasons they can be different (server delay, os thread interruption, the code behind the C# line and C++ lines are surely going to be different, etc). I'd be more surprised they if they were exactly the same. Maybe send the timestamp in the message.

Comment: So you have two different programs, one C++ and the other C#, that receive data "at the same time" but record different arrival times?  Are the programs running on the same machine or different ones?

Comment: FWIW, MSVC's `system_clock` uses `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` and `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, while .NET's `DateTime.Now` uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` and `kernel32::GetSystemTime`.

Comment: @NathanOliver same machine, with high priority and same afinity set

Comment: @EduardRostomyan Re: `same afinity` - if both programs are limited to the same CPU - they can't run at the same time, so the timestamp will never be the same - right?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I mean there is an individual core dedicated to each of them

Comment: Most likely these functions are relying on something that can't be multithreaded, so right there one is going to run before the other.  Then you have different libraries potentially calling different OS API's.  100ms is a little large but that can also be explained away by the core the thread was running on being busy with another process before switching back.  Long story short, this is most likely something that can't be fixed.

Comment: I would try to exclude the framework differences and run two copies of the same program to see if timestamp will get closer to each other. I too think that 100ms is a bit large of a difference.